# How to fix TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?

Tags: python

I have a task in hand, in which I try to multiply coefficient from list cA by string from 2D list K
And arises error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
K = ReadFile(open('C:\\Users\\222\\PycharmProjects\\untitled8\\K.txt'))
cA = ReadFile(open('C:\\Users\\222\\PycharmProjects\\untitled8\\cA.txt'))
matrixA = [[0 for x in range (5)] for x in range (5)]
for i in range (5):
    for j in range(5):
        matrixA[i][j] = cA[i] * K[i][j]
print (matrixA)
```

Comment: what kind of data does K and cA contain? In other words, what does ReadFile return?

Comment: It returns list

Comment: a list of what?

Comment: List of fractional numbers
def ReadFile(f):
    mas = []
    for line in f:
        row = [float(i) for i in line.split()]
        mas.append(row)
    return mas

Comment: use try: to multiply and except: to print the data cA[i] and K[i][j] to locate what isnt what you think it is.

Comment: Was it cA[i] that didn't contain the data you expected? Or what did you figure out after trying my advice?